# CoTaskMemFree to deallocate PIDLs

Tags: winapi

I use `ShBrowseForFolder()` to select a working folder in an application to launch Perl scripts that I am writing.  Once `ShGetPathFromIDList()` has given me the text representation of the chosen folder, the documentation says to call `IMalloc::Free` to release its *PIDL*.  However, the MSDN page describing this shell function says it is heavily deprecated.  Instead it recommends `CoTaskMemFree()` as it is a more modern approach and simpler to use.

Is it safe to use `CoTaskMemFree()` to deallocate *PIDL*s?

Comment: Has been safe [since Windows XP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/05/173226.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115.aspx) documentation says:

> It is the responsibility of the calling application to call **[CoTaskMemFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680722.aspx)** to free the IDList returned by **SHBrowseForFolder** when it is no longer needed.

On the other hand, the [Windows Embedded Compact SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee503764.aspx) documentation says:

> The calling application is responsible for freeing the returned PIDL with the [IMalloc::Free](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488292.aspx) method for the shell allocator. To get a handle to the [IMalloc:IUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee487895.aspx) interface for the shell's allocator, call [SHGetMalloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee500848.aspx).

Now, SHGetMalloc is deprecated [on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762190.aspx) but not [on Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee500848.aspx).

Bottom line: Assuming that you're developing for Windows, go ahead and use CoTaskMemFree.

Comment: Yeah - they do talk at cross purposes and I don't find the new MSDN as convenient or easy to use as the one in Visual Studios past.  I find it VERY hard to turn up specific information or browse generally.  I also take exception to the idea MS are pushing that `ShBrowseForFolder()` should be replaced by the standard file open dialogue with only folders enabled.  That to my mind is counter-intuitive and ugly.  The real `ShBrowseForFolder()` dialogue is far more compact, fit to purpose and visually appealing - which is why I use it!

Comment: From [`SHGetMalloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762190.aspx): *"If you find an older reference document that suggests or even requires the use of **SHGetMalloc**, it is acceptable and encouraged to use **CoTaskMemAlloc** and **CoTaskMemFree** instead."*

Comment: @IInspectable To be clear, that's the SHGetMalloc documentation for Windows.

Comment: I would assume that the information linked to by @RaymondChen above is also true for Windows Compact 2013. If the application/shell extension links against ole32.lib it should then be safe to call [`CoTaskMemFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee489610.aspx), although I don't have the shlobj.h header file for Windows Compact 2013 to see if it contains the same comment.